# Windows 10-kernel security check error when i unplug usb or plug in an usb

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I recently updated to windows 10 and I've been getting these crashes alot when i plug in or unplug an usb or sometimes even randomly just crashes and gives me the kernel security check error message.
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=root&cid=23CDE74496897CDE
Here is the dump file

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: @SanjOO1 please can you put the dumpfile on either pastebin or directly into your post if it is short enough.